# how to display the user input in real time in laravel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

i have a textarea input, and i want to display the user inputs at the below of the user input box at the same time that user writes the text (real time). 
i'm working with laravel framework. 
like what stckoverflow has in the question page...
and this is my html code...

```
    {{ Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) }}
    {{ Form::token() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('title', 'title') }}
        {{ Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'title...']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('body', 'content...') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('body', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '20', 'placeholder' => 'content...']) }}            
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

i mean this 
[image]

Comment: You will need to write some JavaScript to do that. It can't be done solely in PHP.

Comment: you can use ajax jquery to get that

Comment: @GhiffariAssamar Ajax isn't necessary if OP just wants to show the typing user the text. It'd only be necessary if you wanted to show *other* users, or do some sort of processing like Markdown formatting or something.

Comment: can you guide me? give me an example or something like that.. i haven't work much with js

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn thanks so much... you are my hero

Answer (score 0):

```js
var textinput = document.getElementById('textinput');

textinput.onkeyup = textinput.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
#preview {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  color: #303030;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textinput" placeholder="Your text..."></textarea>
<pre>
  <code id="preview">Preview</code>
</pre>
```

If you want something more advanced, you should look into some libraries like https://github.com/markedjs/marked